# Asynchronous wait failed: For Unit Test case swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, asynchronous

My Unit Test case is failing with

```
waitForExpectations(timeout: 50, handler: nil)
```

having error

> Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 50 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations:

```
  func testThatItSummery() {

       let expectation = self.expectation(description: "GET  SUMMERY")

        Request.jobSummary(startDate: startDateStr, endDate: endDateStr).execute().fetchResponseJSON({(_, _, json, error) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Response error:\(error)")
                XCTAssertNotNil(error, "JobSummary Response error")
                expectation.fulfill()
            } else {
                let jobSummaryJson = json["job"]
                XCTAssertNotNil(json, "JobSummary Response")

                expectation.fulfill()
            }
        })
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 50, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: So Request.jobSummary is taking longer than 50 seconds to complete. Is that your question: why is Request.jobSummary taking too long to respond? If so, what is the class Request?